# Registering Web API 2 external logins from multiple API clients with OWIN Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I would like the following architecture (I've made up the product name for this example):

**Web API 2 application running on one server**
http://api.prettypictures.com

**MVC 5 client app running on another server**
http://www.webpics.com

I would like **www.webpics.com** client app to use the Pretty Pictures API to:

- Register new accounts with username and password
- Register new accounts with Facebook/Google/Twitter/Microsoft
- Log in
- Retrieve pictures

All of the above works except registering external accounts with Facebook, Google etc.

I cannot work out the correct flow to create an **external** account from a separate client user of the API.

I have studied most documents available on the authentication flow, like this:
[image]

I have read pretty much everything I can on the new Identity model in OWIN.

I've examined the SPA template in Visual Studio 2013. It demonstrates how to do most of what I need but only when the client and the API are on the same host; if I want multiple clients accessing my API and being able to let users sign up via Google etc. it doesn't work and as far as I can tell the OWIN authentication flow breaks.

Here is the flow so far:

- User browses to **www.webpics.com/Login**
- **www.webpics.com** calls **api.prettypictures.com/Account/ExternalLogins** (with a **returnUrl** set to go back to a callback at **www.webpics.com**) and displays the resulting links to the user
- The user clicks "Google"
- The browser redirects to **api.prettypictures.com/Account/ExternalLogin** with the name of the provider etc.
- The API's **ExternalLogin** action instantiates a challenge to **google.com**
- The browser is redirected to **google.com**
- The user enters their username and password (if they are not already logged in to **google.com**)
- **google.com** now presents the security clearance: **"api.prettypictures.com" would like access to your email address, name, wife, children etc. Is this OK?**
- User clicks "Yep" and is taken back to **api.prettypictures.com/Account/ExternalLogin** with a cookie that Google has set.

This is where I've got stuck. What is supposed to happen next is somehow the client app should be notified that the user has successfully authenticated with **google.com** and be given a single use access code to swap for an access token later on. The client app should have the opportunity, if necessary, to prompt the user for a username to associate with their **google.com** login.

I don't know how to facilitate this.

In fact at this point the browser ends up sat at the **api.prettypictures.com/Account/ExternalLogin** endpoint after the callback from Google. The API is signed in for Google but the client doesn't know how to deal with that. Should I pipe that cookie back to **www.webpics.com**?

In the SPA app, it is done via AJAX and **google.com** will return an token as a URL fragment and it all works nicely because it all sits on one domain. But that defies much of the point of having an "API" that multiple clients can fully use.

Help!

Comment: Hey Josh! I'm currently working on this as well. We have a Web Api and a html5/angularJS SPA that we want to auth using google/facebook. You dont have a blog or a github repo with a demo on how you solved this? Would be very interested!

Comment: Hi Ashkan, unfortunately I don't! Are you running your SPA on a different domain to the Web API (as above)?

Comment: Yes, we are developing a phonegap app so we have a Web API as our backend and a pure html5/angularjs SPA as our frontend on a different domain, this will later on become the app that will be accessing the API from user phones.

Comment: Josh or @AshkanAldini , did you end up solving this? I'm trying to do something similar and Pinpoint's answer was helpful but am still confused about the implementation.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Update: things have changed since I wrote this post in January**: MSFT released their official OpenID connect client middleware and I worked hard with @manfredsteyer to adapt the OAuth2 authorization server built in Katana to OpenID connect. This combination results in a far easier and far more powerful solution that doesn't require any custom client code and is 100% compatible with standard OAuth2/OpenID connect clients. The different steps I mentioned in January can now be replaced by just a few lines:

**Server:**

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectServer(options =>
{
    options.TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/connect/token");
    options.SigningCredentials.AddCertificate(certificate);

    options.Provider = new CustomOpenIdConnectServerProvider();
});
```

**Client:**

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "http://localhost:55985/",

    ClientId = "myClient",
    ClientSecret = "secret_secret_secret",
    RedirectUri = "http://localhost:56854/oidc"
});
```

You can find all the details (and different samples) on the GitHub repository:

https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server

https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server/tree/dev/samples/Nancy

---

Josh, you're definitely on the right track and your **delegated/federated authentication** implementation seems pretty good (I imagine that you've used the predefined OWIN middleware from `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook/Google/Twitter`).

What you need to do is creating your own custom **OAuth2 authorization server**. You have plenty of options to achieve that, but the easiest one is probably to plug the `OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware` in your OWIN Startup class. You'll find it in the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth` Nuget package.

While the best practice would be to create a separate project (often called "AuthorizationServer"), I personally prefer adding it to my "API project" when it is not meant to be used across multiple API (here, you would have to insert it in the project hosting "api.prettypictures.com").

You'll find a great sample in the Katana repository:

https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#tests/Katana.Sandbox.WebServer/Startup.cs

```
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth2/authorize"),
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth2/token"),
    ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true,

    AllowInsecureHttp = true,

    Provider = new OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        OnValidateClientRedirectUri = ValidateClientRedirectUri,
        OnValidateClientAuthentication = ValidateClientAuthentication,
        OnGrantResourceOwnerCredentials = GrantResourceOwnerCredentials,
    },
    AuthorizationCodeProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider
    {
        OnCreate = CreateAuthenticationCode,
        OnReceive = ReceiveAuthenticationCode,
    },
    RefreshTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider
    {
        OnCreate = CreateRefreshToken,
        OnReceive = ReceiveRefreshToken,
    }
});
```

Don't hesitate to browse the whole project to see how the authorization consent form has been implemented using simple Razor files. If you prefer a higher-level framework like ASP.NET MVC or NancyFX, create your own `AuthorizationController` controller and `Authorize` methods (make sure to accept both GET and POST) and use Attribute Routing to match the AuthorizeEndpointPath defined in your OAuth2 authorization server (ie. `[Route("oauth2/authorize")]` in my sample, where I've changed the `AuthorizeEndpointPath` to use `oauth2/` as a path base).

The other thing you need to do is adding an OAuth2 authorization client in your web app. Unfortunately, there's no generic OAuth2 client support in Katana, and you'll have to build your own. I've personally submitted a proposal to the Katana team, but it has been refused. But don't panic, it's rather easy to do:

Copy the appropriate files from the Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google repository located there: https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google/GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationHandler.cs

You'll need `GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationHandler`, `GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationMiddleware`, `GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions`, `GoogleAuthenticationExtensions` (you'll have to remove the first 2 methods corresponding to the Google OpenID implementation), `IGoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider`, `GoogleOAuth2ReturnEndpointContext`, `GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider`, `GoogleOAuth2AuthenticatedContext` and `GoogleOAuth2ApplyRedirectContext`. Once you've inserted these files in your project hosting "webpics.com", rename them accordingly and change the authorization and access token endpoints URL in `GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationHandler` to match the ones you've defined in your OAuth2 authorization server.

Then, add the Use method from your renamed/custom `GoogleAuthenticationExtensions` to your OWIN Startup class. I suggest using `AuthenticationMode.Active` so that your users will be directly redirected to your API OAuth2 authorization endpoint. Thus, you should suppress the "api.prettypictures.com/Account/ExternalLogins" roundtrip and let the OAuth2 client middleware alter 401 responses to redirect the clients to your API.

Good luck. And don't hesitate if you need more information ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your answer, it pretty much pointed me in all the right directions and I'm almost there. I've created my own middleware implementation using the classes you pointed to. What I'm stuck on is when I redirect back to the client's original `redirect_uri`, for example `http://www.webpic.com/signin-prettypictures`, what do I put in the query string so the middleware logs knows what to do?

Comment: (I've tried putting the state in there as a query string parameter, but the middleware seems to just swallow it and redirect me to my client home page)

Comment: Great to hear! I don't know if you've solved your last issue, but I imagine that setting RedirectUri on the AuthenticationProperties passed to IAuthenticationManager.Challenge will do the trick ;)

Comment: This is a great post, since I'm trying to achieve the same result as joshcomley, but believe to have much less experience than both of you. Can you please explain the starting point for this solution. My approach was using out-of-the-box VS 2013 Web API template which would have account controller ready to go with all necessary methods. Then, wanted to create separate MVC application with no security defined and modify it to my needs. Am planing to call API mostly from controller anyway. Am I going in right direction at all???

Comment: hey Josh, I have a similar architecture in my application. Everything seems to work except when the request comes back from facebook, it stays at the identity server (http://myidentityserver.com/api/yumtable/externallogin?provider=Facebook&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=http://myclientapplication.com/&state=vDdxPMx0E73TIlTzznVva6G4ZEkNpTc2e0Wxu7Q22sQ1) and does not redirect to the client application. Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for AuthenticationMode=AuthenticationMode.Active, fixed my problem where User.Identity.IsAuthenticated was always false on the callback (i.e. the External Cookie wasn't being set)

Comment: I just updated my answer to mention an easier approach using Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server, a fork of the OAuth2 authorization server built in Katana and targeting OpenID connect. Feel free to ping me on JabbR if you need more details.

Comment: Hi @Bartosz, did you get an answer to your question? What approach have you taken? Thanks

Comment: Hi Frank Fajardo. It was all quite a while ago, but the approach I have taken was using Thinktecture Identity Server from Thinktecture. I found this particular blog post very useful with regards to how to start the whole thing: http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/03/07/claims-based-authentication-in-net4-5-mvc4-with-c-external-authentication-with-ws-federation-part-1/

Comment: @Pinpoint - Thank you for your updated answer! I know this post was a while ago but I'm trying to do something very similar except the client is not necessarily an MVC app. I hate to ask you to look at another SO question but if you have a few minutes would you mind looking at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487586/intercept-owin-oauth2-authentication-url-for-web-api-3rd-party-login ? I'm really stuck. :(

Comment: @mayabelle: sure, please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487586/owin-oauth2-3rd-party-login-authentication-from-client-app-authorization-from/28488773#28488773

Comment: As how much I love this post, I don't really 'GET' it, I'm having problems with turning the access token from google into an registered account. in MVC this all goes automatic, for an Web API it is a bit more difficult I think. Could you please help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222715/web-api-oauth-login-using-facebook-google

Comment: @CularBytes I'll take a look at your other 'POST'

Comment: @CularBytes Great, I guess I can 'PUT' this aside