# Dotnetnuke OAUTH/OWIN external Login with facebook

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, dotnetnuke, facebook-login, bearer-token, dotnetnuke-8

I developed a module for Dotnetnuke(8) with WebAPI 2 Endpoints via the DNN API
This API is consumed by an Android-App.
To access the functions that are populated via the API, the user needs to authenticate.

I have already implemented the JWT (Json Web Token) Authentication with the WebAPI and login with username/password from the App works fine with this method.

Now I also want to allow users to login via their facebook-login and to get their name and email and photo from their facebook profile to authenticate and authorize them via the DNN-Users-Database and allow/disallow them to use the API functions.

I googled around a lot and read a lot of blogposts and articles about external authentication in the last few days. The following are very interesting and already gave me ann good insight how the process may work:

http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/

[Registering Web API 2 external logins from multiple API clients with OWIN Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167648/registering-web-api-2-external-logins-from-multiple-api-clients-with-owin-identi?rq=1)

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services

but I cannot really find out (and it seems i do not really understand) if and how this can be made working with my dnn-API and the JSON-WebToken Auth  Method in my project.

If anybody can help to get me in the right direction, your help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance and kind regards

Don

**EDIT:** The DNN-API gives all the JWT-Functionality I just need to define the api paths and functions. e.g:
'

```
    <Route("{controller}/{action}/{p1}")>
    <AcceptVerbs("GET")>
    <AllowAnonymous>
    Public Function userInf(ByVal p1 As String) As HttpResponseMessage
        Dim response As New HttpResponseMessage
        Dim pID As Integer = DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalController.Instance.GetCurrentPortalSettings.PortalId
        Dim objUserInfo As New DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserInfo
        objUserInfo = DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.Instance.GetUserById(pID, CInt(p1))
        If Not objUserInfo Is Nothing Then
            If objUserInfo.UserID > 0 Then
                response = Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Username: " & objUserInfo.Username.ToString))
            Else
                ' Not logged in
                response = Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Not found")
            End If
        Else
            ' Not logged in
            response = Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Not logged in")
        End If

        response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", CORS)                        ' <- Allow CORs !!!!
        ' response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Request-Method", "*")
        Return response
    End Function
```

The Api Path for the DNN Web-API is for authentication:
 example.com/DesktopModules/JwtAuth/API/mobile/Login
where I pass the username and password in the request-body as a json-object
(Documentation on dnnsoftware[dot]com / docs / administrators / jwt /)

**This all works as expected. The thing now is how to make work the facebook login as an external login work together with my JWT-AUTH**

Answer (score 0):

Web api doing authentication by itself, yout need to create `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` and configure web api to use methods, there is an example of how web api token based auth works with standart Bearer token.

There `ApplicationOAuthProvider` its a class which generates token for inhereting from [OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthauthorizationserverprovider(v=vs.113).aspx).

To call method from your token generator you need to get to the path `/api/token` and request will automaticly give you token and user Claims, which you will define in your token generator.

```
   public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();

        var oauthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oauthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
    }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy for your suggestions. As I wrote above, I am working on the DotNetNuke CMS - API ...